# EditText Edit Feature in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, mvvmcross

I wonder how could I able to **enable** and **disable** edit feature in the `EditText` in `mvvmcross`.

```
<EditText
   style="@style/InputNumbersEditText"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
   local:MvxBind="Text Age" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `android:editable="false"` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#editable), you should set `android:inputType="none"` to disable input on the `EditText`. If you're looking to bind the `inputType` of the `EditText` with MvvmCross, you can create a [Value Converter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters) which takes an input value from your ViewModel, and returns an answer of type `Android.Text.InputTypes`.

**Example implementation:**

Add a class to your Android project with the following in it:

```
public class EditTextEnabledValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, InputTypes>
{
    protected override InputTypes Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value)
            return InputTypes.ClassNumber | InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal | InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned;

        return InputTypes.Null;
    }
}
```

and in your layout file:

```
<EditText
   style="@style/InputNumbersEditText"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   local:MvxBind="Text Age; InputType EditTextEnabled(MyProperty)" />
```

Where MyProperty is a bindable boolean on your ViewModel. You can use any type as a source type, it doesn't have to be a boolean. Happy converting!

Comment: It works very well. But keyboard is not numeric or decimal. it is default alphabetical keyboard shows up.

Comment: That's likely a problem with how I'm using the flags enum for InputTypes (I wasn't able to test it). Try only returning InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned ?

Comment: I've just been able to test this properly - it was an issue with the enum I was returning. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I had fixed my issue with other way. Created custom binding to binding **Enabled** property of **View**.

Code for custom binding

```
public class ViewEnabledTargetBinding : MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding<View>
{
    // used to figure out whether a subscription to MyPropertyChanged       

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.TwoWay;

    public ViewEnabledTargetBinding(object target, PropertyInfo targetPropertyInfo)
        : base(target, targetPropertyInfo)
    {
    }

    // describes how to set MyProperty on MyView
    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var view = target as View;
        if (view == null) return;

        view.Enabled = (bool)value;
    }

    // is called when we are ready to listen for change events
    public override void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        var view = View;
        if (view == null)
        {
            //MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Error - checkbox is null in CheckboxCheckedTargetBinding");
            return;
        }
    }       

    // clean up
    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);

        if (isDisposing)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Register custom binding class in setup.cs file.

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
            typeof(ViewEnabledTargetBinding),
            typeof(View), "Enabled");
}
```

Apply binding for your view

```
 local:MvxBind="Text Age; Enabled IsEnable"
```